# Trying to create a responsive quiz using JavaScript, but quiz is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to create a trivia. When a user clicks on an option (a button) within the MCQ portion, i want the site to respond immediately, by responding to the user's click (by changing color either to red or green depending on whether the answer is correct). It will also reset color of all buttons to its original color when the user clicks a button, before responding with the respective response of the button that was clicked

I have tried looking through the code but cannot determine my error - whether its a syntax one or a problem with the logic of my code. Appreciate it

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Trivia!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>
        <script>

            // Run script once DOM is loaded
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()  {

                // When correct button is clicked, turns green
                let correct = document.querySelectorAll('.correct');
                let feedbackmcq = document.querySelector('.feedbackmcq');
                let feedbackfrq = document.querySelector('.feedbackfrq');
                let wrongs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrong');

                // Reset colors of the button (1st question)
                function resetColor()
                {
                    for (let i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
                        correct[i].style.backgroundColor = '#d9edff';
                    for (let i = 0; i < wrongs.length; i++) {
                        wrongs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#d9edff';
                    }
                }

                // When correct button is clicked, turns green
                for (let i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
                    correct[i].addEventListener('click', function()  {
                        resetColor();
                        correct[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                    });
                }

                // When wrong button is clicked, turns red
                for (let i = 0; i < wrongs.length; i++) {
                    wrongs[i].addEventListener('click', function()  {
                        resetColor();
                        wrongs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#red';
                    });
                }}


            });

        </script>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                <hr>
                <div>
                    <h3>Who sent you this link?</h3>
                    <button class="correct">Jonathan</button>
                    <button class="wrong">Thomas</button>
                    <button class="wrong">Kiara</button>
                    <button class="wrong">James</button>

                    <p class="feedbackmcq" id="feedback1"></p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h3>Who created this form?</h3>
                    <button class="wrong">Joel</button>
                    <button class="correct">Jonathan</button>
                    <button class="wrong">Kiara</button>
                    <button class="wrong">James</button>

                    <p class="feedbackmcq" id="feedback2"></p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After creating my script, I checked my syntax to ensure that there was not any semicolon / spelling error. I also thought through the logic, but it really seems logical to me.

Here is my pseudocode:

1. For loop looping through all correct buttons, constantly checking for a click on any one of its buttons.
2. If a click is identified, colors of button is resetted
3. Then, I will change the style of the respective button that was clicked

(same for the wrong buttons when pressed)

Comment: the first suggestion I can give after reading  your code is that the `i` variable you are using inside the click event listener, will be evaluated at the time the event will occur, so it won't have the value you are expecting there. You should instead figure out what's the index of the clicked element by retrieving the element firing the event (via event.target) and query some of its property to figure out. Or you won't just need it because you actually just need the element itself

Comment: Your closing braces `}` are messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach your taking is incorrect - don't set eventListeners on the fly based on conditions - rather set them up in the beginning and then use logic to determine what they should or shouldn't do.

- use a single loop on all buttons
- when they're clicked, test if they are 'correct' or not  based on the data-is property (You had these as classes, but really they are more appropriate as [datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- Then we remove any right/wrong classes that may have been applied from that group of buttons. We do that using [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and querySelectorAll() together
- finally, we apply the correct/incorrect class based on the dataset of the clicked button
- you had styles being applied directly, but using classes is a better, more extendable and easier to maintain approach.

** Further help with the code:

```
buttons.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', e => {
```

Here, we are looping through `buttons` which we already defined as 'all the buttons on the page' with `buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')`. This is arrow function syntax, which isn't too important here. For each button (assigned as `b` in the loop) we add an event listener which also uses arrow syntax. Again, not important here but I find it easier to read and code. The event it is listening to is `click` and the task it will perform on click is (as you mentioned) an anonymous function. Unless you need to reuse that code in other parts of the site, it's fine to leave it as an anonymous function.

```
e.target.closest('div').querySelectorAll('button')
```

which says 'Find the closest containing `<div>` tag to `event.target` (the button that was clicked) - and then find all the `<button>` elements inside that div. That becomes an HTML collection that we can iterate through with `forEach` like before.

Then you'll see `....forEach(bb => bb.classList.remove("isCorrect", "isWrong"))`. Again, the `bb` inside is a placeholder for the thing you're iterating through. In this case each of the buttons inside the div.

At that point, we are just adding or removing CSS classes for the effect

```js
// Run script once DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  buttons.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // first lets clear out any existing colorations
    e.target.closest('div').querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bb => bb.classList.remove("isCorrect", "isWrong"))
    if (e.target.dataset.is=='correct') e.target.classList.add('isCorrect')
    else e.target.classList.add('isWrong');
  }))
});
```

```css
button {
  background: #d9edff;
}

button.isCorrect {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

button.isWrong {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <h3>Who sent you this link?</h3>
      <button data-is="correct">Jonathan</button>
      <button data-is="wrong">Thomas</button>
      <button data-is="wrong">Kiara</button>
      <button data-is="wrong">James</button>
      <p class="feedbackmcq" id="feedback1"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Who created this form?</h3>
      <button data-is="wrong">Joel</button>
      <button data-is="correct">Jonathan</button>
      <button data-is="wrong">Kiara</button>
      <button data-is="wrong">James</button>
      <p class="feedbackmcq" id="feedback2"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have an issue understanding some parts of your code as I am relatively new to JavaScript syntax. Based on what I have read online, the arrow refers to creating an annoyomous function. However, what i don't get is what the b represents (does it mean you are creating an annoyomous function named b), and what the bb represent subsequently 2 lines below.

Comment: Take another look. I added a new section called '**Further explanation of the code'. Hopefully that will help